# alphabetically sorted binary search tree in c?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

how can i develop a program which reads words  from a text file and creates an alphabetically sorted binary search tree using those words? here is my code

```
 #include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

struct treeNode {
       char data[20];
       int count;
       struct treeNode *leftPtr, *rightPtr;
 };

int number;

typedef struct treeNode TreeNode;
typedef TreeNode *TreeNodePtr;

void insertNode (TreeNodePtr *treePtr,char word[]);
void alphabetic(TreeNodePtr treePtr);




int main(){

    /*reading strings from the file and add them to the tree*/

    char first[20];
    FILE *fp1;
    TreeNodePtr rootPtr=NULL;
    int c;
    fp1=fopen("output.txt","r");
    do{
        c=fscanf(fp1,"%s",first);
        insertNode(&rootPtr,first);




    }while(c!=EOF);


    fclose(fp1);

    alphabetic(rootPtr);

    system("PAUSE");

}

/*for adding nodes to tree*/

void insertNode (TreeNodePtr *treePtr,char word[20]){
    TreeNode *temp = NULL;
    if(*treePtr == NULL)
    {
        temp = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
        temp->leftPtr = NULL;
        temp->rightPtr = NULL;
        temp->data[20] =  word[20];
        *treePtr = temp;

    }
    else if(strcmp(word,(*treePtr)->data)<0){


        insertNode(&((*treePtr)->leftPtr),word);
    }
    else if (strcmp(word,(*treePtr)->data)>0){


        insertNode(&((*treePtr)->rightPtr),word);
    }
    else{
        number++;
    }
}

/*for sorting alphabetically*/
void alphabetic(TreeNodePtr treePtr){
    if(treePtr!=NULL){
        alphabetic(treePtr->leftPtr);
        printf("%3d\n",treePtr->leftPtr);
        alphabetic(treePtr->rightPtr);
    }
}
```

when i have a .txt including 4 words my program writes onli four 0' s as output.

Comment: What's the point of typedefing `TreeNodePtr`? You're not saving any typing and you're not abstracting away the fact that it's a pointer. I'd get rid of the typedef.

Comment: Your function `alphabetic` doesn't sort anything, it *traverses* the tree. And for some reason displays a pointer as an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
    temp->data[20] =  word[20];
```

It copies a single character from one invalid location to another.

Change it to:

```
    strcpy(temp->data, word);
```

since you want to copy a string.

Also this line looks wrong:

```
    printf("%3d\n",treePtr->leftPtr);
```

I'm guessing you want to print the contents of the `data` string here, so it should be:

```
    printf("%s\n", treePtr->data);
```

or if you want the integer `count` element it would be:

```
    printf("%d\n", treePtr->count);
```

Comment: thanks for your help,it worked :) but i have to count how many times a word exists in the binary tree and i couldn't do this ,how can i do this?

Comment: @user2733502 You could always just traverse the tree and keep a counter.